# Android app to lock the screen with a swype from the bottom of the screen.

Tags: android, lockscreen

My phone's power button is broken and I use an app called Screen Off to lock the phone. But that's only for home screen. If I want to lock the screen while I am in an another app or press the power button to display the lockscreen to see the time, this app is useless. So, isn't there any app that suits my needs?

Comment: With Tasker you can replace the "Hold the home icon and swipe up for Google" functionality to something like locking the screen. I made it so that the "Hold and swipe" would toggle the flashlight.

Comment: Does your device have root privilege ?! Did you try [Button Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en) ?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit My device doesn't have a home 'icon', instead it has only a button.

Comment: @wingedpanther Button Mapper can only customize buttons, I'm looking for an app that can turn the screen off by swiping from the bottom..